# How can I label points in a Taylor diagram?

Tags: r, plot

The [plotrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html) package has a function called `taylor.diagram` that plots two vectors - one representing data and the other model output.

Here is an example:

```
require(plotrix)
set.seed(10)
data  <- sort(runif(100, 8,12))
model <- sort(rnorm(100, 10, 4))
taylor.diagram(data, model)
```

And in this example I want to update the plot after improving the model:

```
model2 <- sort(rnorm(100, 10,2))
taylor.diagram(data, model2, add = TRUE)
```

To produce this:

[image]

How can I add labels such as "Model 1" and "Model 2" to identify these points?  (Update: with the label position determined from the model values rather than done post-hoc)

Answer (score 4):

A third solution is to create a modified version of the function `taylor.diagram` that includes a text label.  In this case all there is to do is adding a parameter, say `text`, and after the call to `points` in the original function (2 lines before the closing braces), the line `text(sd.f * R, sd.f * sin(acos(R)), labels=text, pos=3)`.

```
taylor.diagram.modified <- function (ref, model, add = FALSE, col = "red", 
                                    pch = 19, pos.cor = TRUE, xlab = "", ylab = "", 
                                    main = "Taylor Diagram", show.gamma = TRUE, 
                                    ngamma = 3, gamma.col = 8, sd.arcs = 0, ref.sd = FALSE, 
                                    grad.corr.lines = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9), pcex = 1, 
                                    cex.axis = 1, normalize = FALSE, mar = c(5, 4, 6, 6),
                                    text, ...) #the added parameter
{
    grad.corr.full <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99,1)
    R <- cor(ref, model, use = "pairwise")
    sd.r <- sd(ref)
    sd.f <- sd(model)
    if (normalize) {

    ... #I didn't copy here the full function because it's quite long: to obtain it
    ... #simply call `taylor.diagram` in the console or `edit(taylor.diagram)`.

            }
            S <- (2 * (1 + R))/(sd.f + (1/sd.f))^2
        }
    }
    points(sd.f * R, sd.f * sin(acos(R)), pch = pch, col = col, 
           cex = pcex)
    text(sd.f * R, sd.f * sin(acos(R)),  #the line to add
         labels=text, cex = pcex, pos=3) #You can change the pos argument to your liking
    invisible(oldpar)
}
```

Then simply supply a label name in the `text` argument:

```
require(plotrix)
set.seed(10)
data  <- sort(runif(100, 8,12))
model <- sort(rnorm(100, 10, 4))
taylor.diagram.modified(data, model, text="Model 1")
model2 <- sort(rnorm(100, 10,2))
taylor.diagram.modified(data, model2, add = TRUE, text="Model 2")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches

1. `example(taylor.diagram)` shows a decent approach to placing a legend in the upper right  corner (at `1.5*sd(data), 1.5*sd(data)`), but this would require different colors for the two points.
2. Another option would be to calculate the locations based on the equations from the original [Taylor 2001 reference](http://www-pcmdi.llnl.gov/about/staff/Taylor/CV/Taylor_2001_JGR.pdf) - or copy them from source code to the `taylor.diagram` function, near

   ```
   dy <- 1.1 # text offset coefficient
   sd.f <- sd(model)
   R <- cor(data, model, use = 'pairwise')
   x <- sd.f * R
   y <- sd.f * sin(acos(R)) + dy * sd.f
   text(x, y, "Model")
   ```

   You would need to calculate these for each model, but only the model input and the label would change. You probably want to keep the offset the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you label everything in base graphics, using `text`:

```
text(1.5,0.5,labels = "Model2")
text(3.5,1,labels = "Model1")
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to be able to plot them without advance knowledge of their position

Comment: @Abe The documentation for `taylor.diagram` indicates that it does not return the positions of points (or really any plot information at all) so I don't think you have a lot of options here.